# JxBrowser is displaying the following license isn't compatible error message

Tags: jxbrowser

On client machines that were working fine yesterday we get the following error message:

> The license isn't compatible with the current product version (6.x). The license can be used only with product versions released before 05/05/2016. Current product version was released on 05/05/2016.

We are using Version 6.0.2 and coincidentally our support ran out today.

Any ideas on what we need to do?

Comment: This is particularly bad as there appears to be a bug in the license check code that is triggered after the support contract ends.  The only way to fix this is via a new license or an upgrade to a possibly fixed future version if it exists and if it works without any changes to our code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that you see this issue. The license is valid for all JxBrowser 6.x versions, but several months ago we discovered that the license checking mechanism has issue with parsing the support expiration date. We fixed this issue right away in JxBrowser 6.1. I confirm that JxBrowser 6.0.2 has this issue. To fix it I recommend that you upgrade to JxBrowser 6.1 or higher.